# Django Full example of dropdown menu populated from postgresql database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am pretty new to django (using django 2.1.5 and python 3.7) and I can't seem to figure out how to add a dropdown menu, showing elements of one field from a table in my postgresql database. I want to ultimately allow the user to choose one element from the dropdown menu, and I will build a query with that choice and return results of that query. But I am stuck already with the dropdown menu.
Here is my model in the models.py file

```
class Locations(models.Model):
    gid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field_gid = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='__gid', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed because it contained more than one '_' in a row. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    name_location= models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    x = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    y = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    z = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    geom = geomodels.PointField(srid=3912)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_location

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'locations'
        verbose_name_plural = "Locations"
```

Here is my form in the forms.py file:

```
from .models import Locations
class LocationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Locations
        fields = ('name_location',)
        #Down here is what I actually thought I need, but maybe I am not using it right 
        locations_list = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Locations.objects.all().only('name_location').order_by('name_location'))
```

And then, in my views.py file:

```
from .forms import LocationsForm
def LocationsView(request):
    form = LocationsForm
    return render(request, 'geoportal/mforest.html', {'form': form})
```

My urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='geoportal-home'),
path('mforest/', views.LocationsView, name='geoportal-mforest')
]
```

And finally in my template mforest.html file (I only put an extract because the base.html has a block content that I extend in mforest.html):

```
{% extends "geoportal/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-3" style="height: 100vh; border: 2px red; background-color: lightgray">
    <h3>Meteo Stations of the SFI</h3>
    <form method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
    </form>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <h3>Output of the query</h3>
    <table width="100%" class="blueTable"> </table>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

For the template file, I also tried some suggestions of iterating over the result of the query set. However, None of the solutions I've tried was displaying my dropdown menu. I am sure I am doing something wrong, since I am not getting the expected result, but I don't know what to correct.
PS. I am not getting an error. It is simply not displaying anything.
Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT: More on what I want to achieve, [please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU3or.png) to see what I have on my page (though almost nothing). (Do not pay attention to the label "kraj_odvze" which I replaced in this question by "name_location"). Now; instead of having a textbox, what I actually want is a dropdown menu with elements from the field "name_location" in my database. I will further include a datetimerange picker and a button to perform a query to render as table and graphs on the right-side-div of my page.

Comment: How does your urls.py file look like? btw, a [modelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) should have a `model` attribute specified in the Meta class. **Edit:** Please describe what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @art06 Please look at my edit. THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem, thanks to the comment of @art06 .
Since I am going to be querying another table ("Meteo") which has a column representing a foreign_key that points to the column "name_location" of the "Locations" table, I should use instead the "Meteo" table instead of "Locations".

Therefore, having the models.py file as folows:

```
class Locations(models.Model):
    gid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field_gid = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='__gid', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed because it contained more than one '_' in a row. Field renamed because it started with '_'.
    name_location = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    x = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    y = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    z = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    geom = geomodels.PointField(srid=3912)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ for py2
        return self.name_location

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'locations'
        verbose_name_plural = "Locations"


class Meteo(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    air_temp = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    soil_temp = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    precipitation = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    global_rad = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    relative_hum = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    wind_speed = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    swc = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    pressure = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Locations, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='location', to_field='name_location')  # to_field is required because the Foreignkey field is a text
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'meteo'
        unique_together = (('time', 'id'),)
        verbose_name_plural = "Meteo"
```

and the forms.py as follows:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Meteo
class LocationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Meteo
        fields = ('location',)
```

By changing the previous in what I have in my post, django formats the field as a dropdown menu and it displays well.

**Therefore, the keypoint that I was not getting right here is that:
Even without writing ModelChoiceField, when ModelForm is used with a foreign key, it automatically creates a dropdown menu.**